# Getting error when I try to download file

Tags: android, file, download

I found this source code on the net and have modified it a little. But I get an error saying: java.io.FileNotFoundException /data/datafile.zip.
What should I do to get it running? Do I have to create the file first?

Thanks, Sigurd

```
private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("Zip Download", "Start download");
            File file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "datafil.zip");
            Log.d("Zip Download", file.getAbsolutePath());

            URL updateURL = new URL("http://dummy.no/bilder/bilder/XML_Item_Expo_01.zip");
            URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

            int current = 0;
            while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                baf.append((byte)current);
            }

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.d("Zip Download", "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Zip Download", "Error: " + e);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like permission error. You maybe writing to the wrong place. Check that answer at link below,

[Data directory has no read/write permission in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998400/data-directory-have-no-read-write-permission-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.getDataDirectory()` does not return a path where you can place files.  You should use one of these methods instead:

- `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` gives you a path to external storage (SD card).
- `getFilesDir()` from an Activity or other Context.  Gives a path to app's internal file storage

You can also call `openFileOutput()` with a string file name (no path, just the file), which will open the FileOutputStream and create the file all in one shot for your use.

Hope that Helps!