# Store data on internal storage (even when app is uninstalled)

Tags: android, storage, uninstallation, internal

I am developing an application and I need to store some data in a file in internal storage. The issue is that I need to be able to read the data even when the application is uninstalled. I have read many different solution but none worked for me. I would appreciate if anyone gives me a hint on how to proceed.  The idea is that I store some data on a file in internal storage and even if the user uninstalls the application next time he opens the app, the app should be able to read the content from the file. I tried many solution but all seem to delete the file when the app is uninstalled.

Kind regards

Comment: you should try storing it on sdcard if you want to use data after reinstall.

Comment: The issue is that the application targets a wide range of phones and some phones might not have SD card. I need to be able to store it on internal storage.

regards

Comment: @Boris every phone has External Storage even if there is sdcard or not

Answer (score 1):

Seems like SO has a lot of similar questions. E.g. see [Android: Save file permanently (even after clear data / uninstall)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6108787/2878070). Bytheway, if you consider to keep data somehow - you may try to find some path on internal storage that has RW permissions for all users. Try `/data/local/tmp` directory for example. But anyway you should be aware that this is very fragile approach and IMO just a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using the [external storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). However, you cannot prevent users from manually removing such files using File Browsers. So insert some (null)checks while trying to read your data.