# Binding iOS embedded Framework for Xamarin END UP give exception?

Tags: ios, xamarin, binding, frameworks, native

Please help my last step. 
Thanks.

I'm testing binding iOS native framework to Xamarin library.

1. I created iOS framework and added MyView.h, MyView.m

   - MyView.m

   (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
   {
      id p = [super initWithFrame:frame];
           self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
           return p;
   }

   - MyView.h

   @interface MyView : UIView
   @end

very simple framework.

2. add that MyView.h into Public Header and Made universal framework for any architecture.
   This framework now has

   firstfile.h, MyView.h

two files as public headers

3. I created iOS test app (single VC app) and tried this framework.

   MyView *v = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
       [self.view addSubview:v];

It worked as I expected. It drew a green box.

4. I created Xamarin Library project and import this framework file on Native Reference Folder by clicking right click and add file
5. Add this lines to ApiDefinition.cs in Xamarin Library

   [BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
   interface MyView
   {
       [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
       IntPtr Constructor (CGRect frame);
   }

build OK.

6. I created Xamarin.iOS app and import this library to solution and test it.

   MyView v = new MyView(new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
               this.View.AddSubview(v);

BUILD OK!
but runtime error.

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

As I'm new with CSharp and mono. 
It was not easy to come here, 
Could you help me little bit at this point?

My clue is that there should be something pointing MyView.h in No.5 step. But I don't know what should be there.

my full source code is here : 
https://github.com/myallb/test_iosstaticlib_to_xamarin

This code is using Static Library instead framework. 
I was trying different option.

Comment: Can you share the full source?

Comment: @jzeferino Yes of course. I will make a github repo quickly.

Comment: @jzeferino https://github.com/myallb/test_iosstaticlib_to_xamarin

Comment: This code is using Static Library instead framework. I was trying different option.

Comment: @jzeferino Thanks so much. ^^

Comment: I changed little bit. please download again if you downloaded already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example framework binding....

#### iOS-based `GreenView` Universal Framework (via Xcode):

- Add a new Cocoa Touch Class named `MyView` subclassing `UIView`:

`MyView.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView {
}

@end
```

`MyView.m`:

```
#import "GreenView/MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

- (void)baseInit {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

`GreenView.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double GreenViewVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char GreenViewVersionString[];

#import "MyView.h"
```

#### Sharpie Example (to jump start the `ApiDefinition.cs`)

```
sharpie bind 
   -sdk iphoneos9.3 
   -o GreenViewBinding 
   GreenView.framework/Headers/*.h
```

#### Create a `Xamarin.iOS` Binding Project:

- Add the `GreenView.framework` as a Native Reference

`ApiDefinition.cs`

```
using UIKit;

namespace GreenViewBinding
{
    // @interface MyView : UIView
    [BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
    interface MyView
    {
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

- Create a iOS single view app
- Add the Binding project as a reference.

`ViewController.cs` `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    var view = new GreenViewBinding.MyView();
    view.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(40, 40, 100, 100);
    Add(view);
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Sushi. FIrst of all, Thanks so much for your help. It will be really helpful. I believe I tried exactly you said. But runtime error. I uploaded my new full codes with framework version. https://github.com/myallb/test_iosframework_to_xamarin  If you could check this.. It will be greatful. Thanks again.

Comment: Only thing different with yours is that I did not use sharpie because I know once you gave that, doesn't matter if I run sharpie or not. It's same wrapper.