# EROS | Read Only file system error

Tags: java, android, file, permissions

In my android app, i am logging errors in a txt file. But when i try to create file , i face an error `Java.io.IOException: open failed: EROS( Read Only file system error)`. I have added write permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` but no difference. How to fix it ?

**code**

```
    try {       
          File file =new File("Log.txt");
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.w("tun tun", e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: working on emulator or device ?

Comment: device S3 @HemantChandDungriyal

Comment: context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/log.txt";

Comment: have u try above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way

**To store on external storage(SDCARD)**

```
try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Log.txt");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("tun tun", e.toString());
        }
```

**To store In internal storage**

```
try {
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + "Log.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w("tun tun", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: to save in internal storage it shows error on getCacheDir() @Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: are you writing this code in activity? or out side the activity?

Comment: if you are trying from out side the activity need to write context.getCacheDir()

Comment: what if i want to get it in simple java class ? @Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: any how you need to pass context from your activity to simple java class

Answer (score 1):

try some below codes:-

Problem is you are not adding path.

```
String filePath = context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/fileName.txt";
File f = new File(filePath);
```

or

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

[refrence](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

or

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(path, "/" + fname);
```

[Data directory has no read/write permission in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998400/data-directory-has-no-read-write-permission-in-android)