# How to read file names from Internal storage in Android

Tags: android, internal, android-file

I want to read the file names from the default internal storage folder of my app but even if there are some files I get a List of size 0 I use the following to read the file names

```
File dirFiles = Settings.this.getFilesDir();
    File list[] = dirFiles.listFiles();
    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
        myList.add( list[i].getName() );
    }
```

What I am doing wrong here? is the path I get correct? or it needs to have a "/" at the end of it?

```
/data/data/com.compfrind.contacts/files
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way

```
private File path = new File("/storage/" + "");


    File list[] = path.listFiles();
        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
```

Also please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998400/data-directory-has-no-read-write-permission-in-android) answer

Comment: It works but I am not getting the apps files but storage files

Comment: what files do you want  to get? Any specific app ?

Comment: I want to get the files from the default file folder of the app

Comment: The link suggests to use as in my case the Context.openFileOutput() but I want to get the filenames of all files not the data of a file stored in internal storage

Comment: @MiaoulisNikos You can try using this File path = new File("/storage/emulated/0/.data/.data/com.compfrind.contacts/files" + ""); and then call path.getFiles() , I am not sure 100% but I think it should work !!

Comment: @MiaoulisNikos did you try the suggestion ?

Comment: I had already done this and works with the full path instead of /storage/ but is it best practice?

Comment: The .getName() did it for me. Thanks.